# Is it possible to update GridView with variable number of columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView` linked to a SQL table. Table have unknown or variable number of columns. Both the number of columns and the names of the columns are variable. Is it possible, to setup a dynamic `UpdateCommand` in the `sqlDataSource` so that I can update every column? If yes; how?

Code I tried:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty ="True" DataSourceID="UpdateSqlDataSource"
    CssClass = "table" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
    CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="UpdateID" ShowFooter="True"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateSelectButton ="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <Columns>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID ="UpdateSqlDataSource" runat ="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MachineUpdateDataBaseConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [MachineUpdate] WHERE [UpdateID] = @UpdateID"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MachineUpdate]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE SET [MachineUpdate] = @MachineUpdate WHERE [UpdateID] = @UpdateID[*] = @* WHERE [UpdateID] = @UpdateID">
    <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UpdateID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Whats are you trying to update? The contents of the row?

Comment: Hint: columns.add in a loop.

Comment: @Ewerton, Yes, the content of the row

Comment: Im not sure what you mean @JacobH

Comment: You want to update all rows at once or want to update specific a row?

Comment: A specific row.  Grid views have a built in feature to do so, but you need to set up an update command. @Ewerton

Comment: Well, i think my posted answer shows you how to do it and still use the "update built in feature"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UpdateCommand of your SqlDataSource is always static, to generate an dynamic update, your should do it by C# code handling the RowUpdating event of the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string sqlCommand = "UPDATE YourTable SET ";
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in e.NewValues)
    {
        // You will need to take care to not update PK, FK, etc
        // You will need to handle DB restrictions
        // You will need to handle DataTypes (eg: Not set a boolean in a Date column)
        sqlCommand = sqlCommand + item.Key + " = " + item.Value + ",";
    }

    sqlCommand = sqlCommand.TrimEnd(','); // removes the last comma

    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in e.Keys)
    {
        //Assuming that you will have just only one key
        // You can get the Key in the GridView.DataKeyNames property as well
        sqlCommand = sqlCommand + " WHERE " + de.Key.ToString() + " = " + de.Value.ToString();
    }


    GridView grd = (GridView)sender;
    SqlDataSource ds = (SqlDataSource)grd.DataSourceObject;
    ds.UpdateCommand = sqlCommand; // Modify the UpdateCommand of you SqlDataSource
}
```

**Note:** Update columns dynamically isn't a good idea, you will have more headache than benefits. But for simple scenarios, the above code could work.